# How to list all mp3 files in a Folder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, file

I want add all MP3 files into a list in JavaScript.

and set one Song after another as

```
var foo=new Sound("/Users/alexw/Music/test.mp3",100,true);
```

Comment: it's a function i wrote, not necessary for  the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access data files from your file system via Javascript, it's a security issue

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

EDIT:
to access files there's 2 solution:

using a custom DLL (for ex. made with C# in Internet Explorer) you can load via javascript that list your computer files

using a local web service (for ex. made with Node.js) to list your files and stream them if you want online

Comment: Okay, but why can i access the test.mp3 file?
I can play it with my own written Music Player.

Comment: you can access local file because you know the URL. Your local DNS creates a reference URL to access files, but can't list a folder content. You have to build your own personal server/web server/web service (for exemple with nodejs) to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I use node walk, it works!

```
function getAllFilesFromFolder(){
  var walk    = require('walk');
  var files   = [];

  // Walker options
  var walker  = walk.walk("/Users/alexw/Music", { followLinks: false });

  walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
      // Add this file to the list of files
      files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
      next();
  });

  walker.on('end', function() {
      console.log(files);
  });
}
```